# Wildfly 10 - Cannot Upload Spring WAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

When I try to upload my spring app to wildfly I get the error below, if I run the app in STS it runs fine with no errors.

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/dealer_app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/dealer_app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\": java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Class;)V Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Class;)V"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/dealer_app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\""],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<artifactId>dealer_app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- GSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be due to you not having the jboss dependency included in your pom.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-undertow -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-undertow</artifactId>
<version>8.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This might do the trick, if not it may be because you're using a method not specified in the Jboss library. Hope this helped!

Comment: HI, When I add jboss I get an error saying "Missing artifact sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk" Thanks

Answer (score 0):

excluding tomcat from spring-boot-starter-web is not enough.

You have to change your start class like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

If it still does not work yet, you have to repackage your app:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.DemoApplication</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestions, this worked for my resource app but my auth app has the same error as above after I made the suggested changes